# Calling a Python function using two sets of brackets

Tags: python, function, currying, function-calls

For an assignment I have to create a function that should go over a list with numbers, and use each number of this base as the power of a certain base. These numbers should be added up. So for instance, the list [1,2,3] with base 10 should result in 1110 (10^1+10^2+10^3). I could quite easily create a code for this:

```
def f(base,list1):
    answer=0
    for i in list1:
        answer+=base**i
    return answer
```

The testing environment however tests this function by calling the code f(list1)(base), for different testlists and testbases. When using this method of calling this does not work for my code. So how can I edit my code, in such a way it works by calling f(list1)(base)?

Comment: Why do you need to? What's wrong with ` f(list1, base)`? (There is a concept of 'currying' a function so you could get g = f(list1); g(base)`, but I don't see why you need to?

Comment: Your `f` should only take `list1`, and **return a function** that takes `base`.

Comment: Because it is for an assignment where in which I learn how to code in python. The assignment code is tested by a computer, that tests the function using random lists and random bases. It tests the function by calling the function using f(list1)(base).

Comment: I tagged this 'currying' because that's what the concept is called.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with your code, but you should package it in another function and return that:

```
def f(list1):
    def f2(base):
        answer=0
        for i in list1:
            answer+=base**i
        return answer
    return f2

res = f([1,2,3])(10)
print (res)
```

Comment: This is implementing currying without using [functools.partial](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html). Same concept.

Comment: For what it's worth, this can be written more concisely using `sum()` and a lambda expression: `def f(list1): return lambda base: sum(base ** i for i in list1)`

Answer (score -1):

Yes, there's a concept called 'currying', implemented by [functools.partial](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html). This allows you to create a new function where some of your args or kwargs are associated with values.

```
import functools
f2 = functools.partial(f, base=10)
f2(list1=[1,2,3]) # Note you have to call f2 with a keyword arg...
1110 # Right answer

f2([1,2,3]) #...it errors if you use the normal (positional) arg 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: f() got multiple values for keyword argument 'base'
```

Comment: Currying a function with multiple arguments means to transform it to a sequence of functions each taking one argument.  While `functools.partial()` can be used to set the arguments one by one, it can't curry the function:  It will never return a function returning a function when the original function doesn't return a function.  This doesn't answer the question either.